# *ngFor generated mat-button is focused on load

Tags: html, angular, button, focus

I'm generating a list of buttons using ngFor and when I load the site, the first generated button is already focused until I click anywhere else ...

`<div align="center" class="buttonDiv" *ngFor="let tamplates of caseService.availableTaskTemplates">
  <button mat-button class="button" *ngIf="tamplates.contentType == 1" (click)="createTask(tamplates.taskType)">
    {{ tamplates.headerText }}
  </button>
</div>`

here's a picture:
https://ibb.co/imG7sy

what can I do to "unfocus" the button?

Answer (score 1):

you can use  **autofocus**  property in HTML.

> autofocus: focus on the element once the page is loaded

add it to a dummy element in your HTML in order to un focus the meta-button.

for example:

```
<label autofocus> </label>
```

---------------- Another Solution -------------------

you can use blur() method in javascript, after the view is rendered.

inside AfterViewInit

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-cmp', 
    templateUrl: `my-cmp.html`
})
class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('buttonsList') buttonsList;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // execute blur on the first child of the list.
    this.buttonsList.nativeElement.firstChild.blur();
  }
}
```

in your template:

```
<div #buttonsList *ngFor='let item of items'>
    <button meta-button> {{item}} </button>
</div>
```

Comment: nothing changed ... I tried it with a <label> tag as well as in the <h2> header above ...

Comment: second solution also didn't work :-/
I'm now trying to solve it by changing the focused background-color into the same color as when unfocused ...

Comment: ok, when I set the focused background-color to red, it works ... but when I set it to the color the button would have unfocused it's just being ignored ...
Seems as if material decides for me